# How can you find two different values in an int array?

Tags: java, arrays

If I have multiple sets of arrays and I want to see if two values are contained in any of the arrays how would I go about doing that.

Here is what I had tried before:

```java
public boolean multiIdTasks(int[] arrayToTest, int slayerTask, int npcKilled){
    for(int j = 0; j < arrayToTest.length; j++){
        if(arrayToTest[j] == slayerTask){
            if(confirmSlayerKill(arrayToTest, arrayToTest[j])){
                return true;
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean confirmSlayerKill(int[] arrayToTest, int npcKilled){
    for(int g = 0; g < arrayToTest.length; g++){
        if(arrayToTest[g] == npcKilled){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I need to check if the npc killed is contained in the array of the task that was given. For example, if your task is a bird and you kill an eagle I want the task's count to decrease, but I have yet to find a good way to check for both the values of the task and the value of the npc killed.

The method that calls this is here:

```java
public boolean getValidKills(int slayerTask, int npcKilled){
    if( multiIdTasks(SlayerData.BANSHEES, slayerTask, npcKilled) || 
        multiIdTasks(SlayerData.BATS, slayerTask, npcKilled) ||  
        multiIdTasks(SlayerData.BIRDS, slayerTask, npcKilled) || 
        multiIdTasks(SlayerData.BEARS, slayerTask, npcKilled)  ||  
        multiIdTasks(SlayerData.CAVE_BUGS, slayerTask, npcKilled)  ||  
        multiIdTasks(SlayerData.CAVE_SLIMES, slayerTask, npcKilled)  ||  
        multiIdTasks(SlayerData.COWS, slayerTask, npcKilled)  ||  
        multiIdTasks(SlayerData.DESERT_LIZARDS, slayerTask, npcKilled)  ||  
        multiIdTasks(SlayerData.DOGS, slayerTask, npcKilled)  ||  
        multiIdTasks(SlayerData.DWARVES, slayerTask, npcKilled)  ||  
        multiIdTasks(SlayerData.GHOSTS, slayerTask, npcKilled)  ||  
        multiIdTasks(SlayerData.GOBLINS, slayerTask, npcKilled)  ||  
        multiIdTasks(SlayerData.ICEFIENDS, slayerTask, npcKilled)  ||  
        multiIdTasks(SlayerData.MINOTAURS, slayerTask, npcKilled)  ||  
        multiIdTasks(SlayerData.MONKEYS, slayerTask, npcKilled)  ||  
        multiIdTasks(SlayerData.SCORPIONS, slayerTask, npcKilled)  ||  
        multiIdTasks(SlayerData.SKELETONS, slayerTask, npcKilled)  ||  
        multiIdTasks(SlayerData.SPIDERS, slayerTask, npcKilled)  ||  
        multiIdTasks(SlayerData.TROLLS, slayerTask, npcKilled)  ||  
        multiIdTasks(SlayerData.WOLVES, slayerTask, npcKilled)  ||  
        multiIdTasks(SlayerData.ZOMBIES, slayerTask, npcKilled)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

If `getValidKills` is true then the count should decrease. But I cant get this to work properly, can anyone help? If you need more information then let me know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    /**
 * Search for {@code value1} and {@code value2} in {@code array} array.
 * 
 * @param array given array to be searched.
 * @param value1 value to be searched.
 * @param value2 value to be searched.
 * @return true if found both values in the given array.
 */
private static boolean hasBothValues(int[] array, int value1, int value2) {
    int totalMatches = 0;
    for (int value : array) {
        if (value == value1 || value == value2)
            totalMatches++;
        if (totalMatches >= 2)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Consider adding some comments to your sample code explaining what you're doing. Note also that your code doesn't work correctly if either `value1` or `value2` exist in the array twice, while the other might not. :-)

Comment: The above code worked properly with one minor change, if the values are equal then it should return true always, otherwise it needs to loop through the specified arrays to check if any array contains both of the values. Thanks for the answer buddy, and thanks for your help Gijs.

Comment: I would like to also note that neither of the values being checked would be contained in the array two times, I wrote up the arrays myself and this is exactly the answer I was looking for